# What is this plumbing contraption?

Tags: plumbing

Trying to understand what does this set up do. It seems to be related to lawn watering set up.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have an incorrectly mounted "spin-down filter" set up as a "spin-left filter" - open the red valve on the left end to blow out accumulated crud, which is supposed to be collected there by gravity if oriented correctly with that valve on the bottom.

The other thing is a Distributor valve - turns on part of the sprinklers because running all of them at once would drop supply pressure too much.

All that PVC piping should be protected from sunlight - it will embrittle and crack if not.

Comment: Appreciate the pun about the filter. Is it in place to not clog the sprinklers?

Comment: Presumably that's the intent. Keep sand or other particles/flakes out of the sprinkler orifices. There are different types and meshes of filter screen that go in them, which are somewhere between long lasting and permanent, but part of the appeal is that they don't pile everything on the filter, since the water is "whirled" at high speed and throws heavy stuff outwards - where it will fall down if correctly oriented. And opening the dump valve roughly cleans the filter screen, so complete disassembly to throughly clean it can be rare. Also, you can see what it's collected.

Comment: I have one (similar, not exactly the same as this) on my system to catch crud from the well before it causes any trouble elsewhere. I use the finest Stainless Steel mesh they make for it to approximate permanent. They make finer polyester filter meshes, which are less permanent, but if you want fine filtration, this would just be a nice pre-filter to get the big stuff out before a cartridge filter (that you'd have to replace regularly.) What my well throws when it does is coarse enough that the fine stainless works for my purposes. For sprinklers, if it goes through the hole, it's small enough

Comment: Just a comment on PVC piping and UV light. Some pipes are now highly UV resistant (due to addition of titanium dioxide in the manufacturing process) and are marketed as having a "50 year outdoors" lifetime. Of course you should assume all unknown PVC pipes are potentially UV vulnerable. An excellent method of protecting is simply to paint (an alkyd based general-purpose primer covered by your choice of spray paint).